# Writing a quiz application

Tags: c#, asp.net

im making a quiz application in asp.net using c#. The following code is my start page where on clicking on start i'm redirected to my questions page.
The only reason I've added a start.aspx page ... so I could initialize the
values in the Session.
Here in the page_load event the- request.QueryString["testid"] always resulting to null?
 i.e my if condition is never true and everytime i'm redirected to my "default.aspx" page.
what is the reason?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;

namespace TESTPROJ2
{
    public partial class START : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList();

            Session.Add("answerlist", a1);
            Session.Add("quizid", 1);

            if (Request.QueryString["testid"] != null)
            {
                int testID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["testid"]);
                Session.Add("quizid", testID);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("DEFAULT.aspx");
            }
        }

        protected void startB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("QUEST.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you setting the form to submit via `GET` method? Does the form have an input with name `testid`?

Comment: Looks fine to me, what is the full URL (with query string) you are actually requesting?

Comment: Also try testing for `if (Request.QueryString["testid"].Length > 0)`, it might be returning an empty string.  Also, make sure your querystring is well formed

Comment: If testid isn't visible in the url-bar in your browsers, it won't be in the querystring. How are your navigating to this start page?

Comment: None relevant question, why are you using UPPERCASE on all your .aspx files? This can become troublesome with some older OS and perhaps even newer as well

Comment: Not relevant but... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you put it into Session you cannot see it in QueryString because you use the Response.Redirect without adding anything to GET method (QueryString)

```
protected void startB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int testId = 10;
   Response.Redirect("QUEST.aspx?testid=" + testId);
}
```